# SQL Server 2008 column select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

In SQL Server, if I got a table with like 20 columns and I want 18 of them, can I say something like `* minus columnname1, columnname2,` course right now I write them all.

But if you could it would be much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. However if you are using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 / 2005 you can right click on the table and select the "Script Table as > SELECT To" menu option. This will save you typing the column names, or purchase Red-Gate's SQL Prompt

Answer (score 3):

Little hint to replace the asterisk with column names in SQL Management Studio in no time without any fancy plugin:

1. Select your written query (no matter how many joins, etc.)
2. Right click and select "Design Query in Editor..."
3. Simply click "Ok"

The asterisk should have been expanded to column names now :)

Ofc it's possible to select/deselect any column in the query editor..

Hth

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box - no, it's not possible. You have to spell out all the columns you want explicitly.

With SQL Server Management Studio 2008, there is intellisense which can help you select columns from a table - so that's certainly one step to help ease the pain.

Add-in tools like [SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) offer more help - in SQL Prompt, you can type

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
```

and if you have the cursor just after the asterisk symbol (`*`), you can press `<TAB>` and expand the asterisk into the list of all columns for that table (and then remove the two you don't want) - or you can popup a window and pick those columns you really want.

[image]
Very handy, very useful, very much speeding up development - but it's not a free tool.....

Comment: i have seen some videos and comment about it and it looks really nice. but it wasn't so you know any free alternative. for it costs $ 195..

Comment: @saadan: no, I don't know any free alternatives that are worth trying. SQL Prompt is worth every penny it costs, in the long run!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select TOP (18) * from givenTable` is you want 18 rows.

There is no such method for columns. In fact column names are stored in master db and you can extract them and consruct query looking like what you are asking for BUT it would not be easier than just select field1,field2 ... field18 from blaBlaBla.

```
SELECT table_name=sysobjects.name,
         column_name=syscolumns.name,
         datatype=systypes.name,
         length=syscolumns.length
    FROM sysobjects 
    JOIN syscolumns ON sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
    JOIN systypes ON syscolumns.xtype=systypes.xtype
   WHERE sysobjects.xtype='U'
         and sysobjects.name='myTableName'
ORDER BY sysobjects.name,syscolumns.colid
```

will give you the list of your columns. You can write select generator based on this query.

Comment: yes, that I know well. my mistakes
i ment like 

SELECT * minus column1, column2 FROM tabl1;

Comment: That's selecting the top 18 **rows** - the OP is talking about selecting **18 of the 20 columns** for each row....

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add to the answer of, "No, it's not possible directly in SQL". I would **love** to have that feature too! It sucks when you're trying to do some quick debugging on a 10+ column table that has a varbinary(max).

But I really just want to point out an alternative to Kane's tip for SSMS 2008 (Sql Server Management Studio).

If you open the Object Explorer (right-click in the query window and choose "Open Server in Object Explorer"), navigate to the node for the table in question. Expand the node so you can see the "Columns" node. Now "drag" the Columns node over to your query window and "drop" it. It will paste in all the column names for the table--and you can use it directly in a SELECT clause.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible as far as I know.

Comment: okay actually what I had expected, but could otherwise be nice

Comment: @saadan Generally it is a good practice to do not use * operator in select statements, it is usable for brief tests, ad hoc queries.

Comment: IMHO, there are some cases where `*` fits better than an explicit column list. For example, it seems more natural to use it in EXISTS subselects. Also, when I want to add a couple of columns to a subquery where I have already specified all the columns explicitly, I prefer using `*` rather than listing all the columns all over again (at least when the list is quite long). But that's probably a matter of taste.

Comment: @Andriy M: I am talking about situations where your application expects given count of columns, but uses query with *.. and then someone adds another column. In case of 'exists' you're right of course.

Comment: @nimwith: I see. Even worse when a column is dropped from the table. So I agree, it's much safer to have the column list strictly defined.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a script for easy copy/pasting multiple columns, you might find it useful. See:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/102375/

The script is explained in detail there, but in short for those who do not have an account on sqlservercentral: 
It's a stored procedure that i can run using a shortcut. Type in your tablename (also works with temp tables and views), highlight it, hit the shortcut and it will display the columns of the table. From there you can easily copy multiple columns (the columns are also shown with a comma in front of the column name, so that also saves you some typing) and paste it in your query screen.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ColumnSelect]
    @FullObjectName varchar(200)
AS
/*
    Author: Robin van Schaik
    Version: 1.3 (03-OCT-2012)
*/

DECLARE @Object varchar(200)
DECLARE @Schema varchar(200)
DECLARE @Database varchar(200)
DECLARE @IsTempTable bit
-- Break down parameter in Database/Schema/Object
SET @Object = PARSENAME(@FullObjectName,1)
SET @Schema = ISNULL(PARSENAME(@FullObjectName,2),'dbo')
SET @IsTempTable = case when left(@Object,1)='#' then 1 else 0 end
SET @Database = case when @IsTempTable=1 then 'tempdb' else PARSENAME(@FullObjectName,3) end

EXEC(
'SELECT 
    b.Name as ColumnStart
,   '',''+b.Name as ColumnNext
,   ''[''+b.Name+'']'' as ColumnStartBr
,   '',[''+b.Name+'']'' as ColumnNextBr
FROM
' +@Database+'.sys.objects a
INNER JOIN
' +@Database+'.sys.columns b
ON a.object_id=b.object_id
INNER JOIN
' +@Database+'.sys.schemas d
ON a.schema_id=d.schema_id
WHERE
    a.Object_ID=OBJECT_ID('''+@Database+'.'+@Schema+'.'+@Object+''')
AND d.name = '''+@Schema+'''
'
)
```